# v-for under v-if condition, v-else doesnt work, loop duplicate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop, if-statement, element-ui

Code wrote by **Vue** language, using **Element-ui** framework,

If one object contains something, it displays, if not the menu button disable.

The output should be like:

*a, b(disable), c, d, e*

But mine is like:

*a, a(disable), b(disable), c(disable), d(disable), e(disable), c, d, e*

If the v-if statement and v-else-if statement flips, output is like:

*a(disable), b(disable), c(disable), d(disable), e(disable), b, a(disable), b(disable), c(disable), d(disable), e(disable), a(disable), b(disable), c(disable), d(disable), e(disable), a(disable), b(disable), c(disable), d(disable), e(disable)*

So, I guess if **if-else** condition is true, **for loop** display whether it gotta display, not the certain item that pass the condition.

If array contains something, array and its child display.

```
<el-menu
     :default-active="activeIndex"
     mode="horizontal"
     @select="handleSelect">

     <el-submenu
          v-if="item.subCategories && item.subCategories.length <= 0"
          v-for="(item, index) in category.categories" :index="(index+1).toString()"
          :key="item.parentCategory.categoryId">

          <template slot="title">
               {{ item.parentCategory.categoryName}}
          </template>

          <el-menu-item
               index="(index+1).toString()-(i+1).toString()"
               v-for="(child, i) in item.subCategories"
               :key="child.categoryId"
               @click="searchEventByCategory(item.parentCategory.categoryId, child.categoryId)">
                    {{ child.categoryName }}
          </el-menu-item>
     </el-submenu>
```

If array contains nothing, the menu cant be clicked and of course it doesnt have child.

```
     <el-submenu
          v-else-if="item.subCategories && item.subCategories.length > 0"
          disabled
          v-for="(item, index) in category.categories" :index="(index+1).toString()"
          :key="item.parentCategory.categoryId">

          <template slot="title">
               {{ item.parentCategory.categoryName}}
          </template>

          <el-menu-item>
          </el-menu-item>

     </el-submenu>
</el-menu>
```

By the way, is it possible for if the object contains nothing, the object display as **el-menu-item** which is independent menu item, not **el-submenu** that has second level menu.

please help me!!!
Thank you.

Comment: I might not got it right, but it seems like you just need to put your "v-if="item.subCategories && item.subCategories.length <= 0" condition inside <el-submenu/> element, but couldn't be that simple =)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the 'disabled' property dynamically with `v-bind:disabled` (shorthand: `:disabled`). Then you don't need to duplicate for loops or do any v-if shuffling.

```
<el-menu
     :default-active="activeIndex"
     mode="horizontal"
     @select="handleSelect">

     <el-submenu
          v-for="(item, index) in category.categories" 
          :index="(index+1).toString()"
          :key="item.parentCategory.categoryId"
          :disabled="item.subCategories && item.subCategories.length <= 0"> // set disabled property dynamically if this statement is true

          <template slot="title">
               {{ item.parentCategory.categoryName }}
          </template>

          // If item.subcategories doesn't exist or has no items, this for loop won't render anything.
          <el-menu-item
                v-for="(child, i) in item.subCategories"               
                :index="(index+1).toString()-(i+1).toString()"
                :key="child.categoryId"
                @click="searchEventByCategory(
                item.parentCategory.categoryId,child.categoryId
                )">
                    {{ child.categoryName }}
          </el-menu-item>
     </el-submenu>
</el-menu>
```

[It's not advised to use v-if and v-for on the same element.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-v-if)

Comment: From that comment about about it being ill advised: `When they exist on the same node, v-for has a higher priority than v-if. That means the v-if will be run on each iteration of the loop separately. This can be useful when you want to render nodes for only some items, like below:` . This was the issue I had.

Comment: Note that Vue 3 changes this interaction to give v-if precedence. This was changed because of the ambiguity when v-if and v-for are combined. They suggest using computed properties to calculate a filtered list of items and iterate over that instead. https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-if-v-for.html